# Is Sysmon.exe modifying root certificate legit activity

Tags: certificates, windows, soc

Today I got an alert on my Elastic SIEM that sysmon.exe has modified or created a root certificate.

I tried to look for the certificate thumbprint in the Microsoft trusted root program and could not find it there.

Is this legitimate behavior ? Please note I have not updated sysmon.

[image: Detection details]

Answer (score 1):

While we cannot ensure if this is a false positive, it does looks a bit suspicious, I would dig further on the thumbprint of the certificate.

You can follow this [article](https://posts.specterops.io/code-signing-certificate-cloning-attacks-and-defenses-6f98657fc6ec) that will guide you to inspect the binary blob with PowerShell to see if anything looks funky.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article @raDiaSmO, I checked the hash of the running sysmon process, the path for sysmon etc and it seems legit, so it does not seem to be malware signed by a cloned cert.